# Multi monitor windows positioning problem

Tags: windows-7, windows, multiple-monitors

I need a good multi monitor tool mainly to gain control over the windows positioning. I have problem that closed window/application remembers at which monitors it was (closed). I have disconnect this monitor (this is often LCD TV) I have problem with this "remembering" windows/applications that was closed in LCD TV are out of sight when LCD TV is disconnected.

What is the best practice to deal with this problem other that that not to close windows on this monitor)? Are there any good multi-monitor software to deal with this?

Comment: Funny the user never stated what operating system they are using and yet you assume windows?

Comment: MrStatic: You are right, but user deleted comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try to switch off two-screen mode in desktop properties. In my case only few very specific programs remain out of scope. OS win7.

Comment: Well I can't switch off two screen mode, because I have three monitors, and I have the problem with the fourth - LCD TV. ;)

Answer (score 0):

[UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) is good and does it all IIRC. There is a 30 day trial.

Answer (score 0):

If this is not very common you can just choose program in taskbar, click `ALT+Space`, choose move with keyboard and use arrow keys to get it back in sight. Free and fast ;). But of course if this is happening all the time, it's no solution.